# Initializing a string with data does not pass into javascript

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string like so:

`NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`
`text` is not that long of a string
then I try to pass it into a JS method like so:

```
NSString *theJSMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"magswipeplugin.loadUniData('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')", text,text,text,text,text];
NSLog(theJSMethod);
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: theJSMethod];
```

however It does not pass anything through, but when i set `text` to something like `@"123"` it works perfectly well.

Comment: How long is "very long"?

Comment: like 100 characters maybe

Comment: have you tried just passing one argument first and then gradually increasing the arguments one by one to see where exactly it breaks?

Comment: i tried passing 5 at the same time of `@123` that works without a problem that does not work

Comment: @TooTiredToDrink 100? That's short, not very long at all.

Comment: @rmaddy ok long short whatever, I'll correct that, but just because we say it short doesn't help me solve the problem

Comment: Actually it does. If by "very long" you meant megabytes then the problem could have been a limit on the amount of Javascript this method can handle. Now that we know your strings are really short, we can eliminate that possible issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly escape what you're passing in. You're probably passing in something that makes it invalid javascript.

If all of the text is valid, then you might be exceeding some max length of text that it will let you pass in. Or if it's something that will take a long time to execute in javascript, it could be exceeding the 10 seconds of execution time that is allowed.

Comment: Here is an example of what this could be: `B0000000000000000^SOMETHING/SOMETHING A^1701101000000000000000252000000?`